# SwiftUI Navigation Bar Title

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm making my very first steps into SwiftUI following HackingWithSwift course. I have a problem trying to implement navigation bar in my app. For some reason the title does not show up.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ...
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("WeSplit"))
    }
}
```

Once running it in simulator or on my target device I see free space for the navigation bar title but no text there.
[image]

I've also tried typing `.navigationBarTitle("WeSplit")` with no Text() in there. Result's still the same.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

I'm running Xcode Version 12.3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be inside `NavigationView`, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ...
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("WeSplit"))     // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```